# Maven for Eclipse plugin m2ecplise installation

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I want to try out this websocket implementation:
https://jwebsocket.org/documentation/installation-guide/eclipse

The project is provided with maven. Thus I want to install the m2eclipse plugin as suggested on their site.

The problem is that the provided link does not work:
http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e

I also tried this one:
http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/

Both are not working. 
Can someone give me a hint how to install this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is outdated, referring to Eclipse 3.3 and 3.5.

Maven integration is part of Eclipse itself now. If you download a current Eclipse bundle it can be part of it. http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php?release=kepler

If you downloaded the "classic" version go to `Help > Install New Software`, select the update site for your version (should be "Kepler") and select the Maven integration via filter or category ("Collaboration").